# req.session with different domains node.js

Tags: node.js, cookies, jwt, next.js, cross-domain

I'm building an app using next.js and node.js (express).

The client run on localhost:4000, and the server run on lovalhost:3000.

to communicate between the two domains Iwm using cors().

to authorization i'm using with cookieSession and jwt.

```
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    signed: false,
    secure: false,
    sameSite: false,
  })
);
```

when user login i put on the session a jwt.

```
 req.session = {
```

jwt:userJwt
};

this time the user needs to be identified by the cookie.

this works nice in postman environment, when a user sign in he is identified, the cookie with his jwt is saved.
but when i try to make the same request via the client unforteantually the cookie is not saved.

**the client code:**

```
   const signin= () => {
   const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
   const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

   const {doRequest, errors} = useRequest({
    url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/auth/signin',
    method: 'post',
    body: {
    email,password
   },
   onSuccess: () => Router.push('/')
  });
```

**the useRequest hook:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState }  from 'react';

const useRequest= ({url, method, body, onSuccess}) => {
const [errors, setErrors] = useState(null);
const doRequest =async () => {
try {
  setErrors(null);
  console.log(url);

  const response = await axios[method](url,body);
  console.log(response);
  
  if(onSuccess) {
   onSuccess(response.data);
  }
  
   return response.data;
 } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
   setErrors(
    <div className= "alert alert-danger" >
       <h4>Ooops...</h4>
       {error.response.data ?
       <ul className="my-0">
         {error.response.data.errors.map(err => (
          <li key = {err.message}> {err.message}</li>
        ))}
     </ul>:{}
  }
   </div>
   );
  }
 };

return { doRequest,errors }
};

export default useRequest;
```

Maybe because the diffrent domains the session is not the same?

How can I slove it?

[My app](https://github.com/BrandIl/HOK__PROJECT)

I hope I was clearly.

thank you!

I'm using process.env variables

Comment: Please add to your question the relevant client code when making the request. That code should be pasted into your question as text and formatted as code properly.  External links to repositories are OK for ancillary references, but should not be the only source of information for the code needed to answer the question.  This is because repositories change over time, rendering the original question/answer meaningless as a longer term reference for others to read and learn (which is part of the stackoverflow mission).

Comment: Wild guess: Your axios calls from client to server, need the `withCredentials: true` option set so that they will send cookies with the request.

Comment: Where'd you go?  Perhaps you're new to stackoverflow, but you don't just post and disappear here.  Your main opportunity for help is in the first 30-60 minutes after posting (that's when the most people will see it).  If you get an engagement and you aren't around to answer questions, you may just miss your opportunity for help or others will come along and see you're being unresponsive so they'll just move on to other questions.  Or, by the time you do come back, the one or two people who tried to help have gone on to other things.

Comment: You are right, I'm realy new to stackoverflow. Thank you for enlightening my eyes. if you still there, If you're still here, I edited my question and added the client code.